# Are there ticket offices for Georgian Railways in Tbilisi?

Tags: trains, tickets, georgia-country, tbilisi

In Batumi I happened to know where there was a ticket office in the old town to buy railway tickets because I lived nearby. But it had no sign at all and would be very difficult to find if you didn't already know it was there. It was very handy though because the train station was 5km outside the city.

But now I'm in Tbilisi and the long distance train station is also not very handy but I don't know, and can't find on the internet, if there are also Georgian Railways ticket offices here besides at the station.

I've looked at [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Tbilisi#By_train) and the [Georgian Railways website](http://www.railway.ge) and don't know where else to look.

Comment: Why not purchase them online? http://tickets.railway.ge/login.aspx?lang=en-US

Comment: @Giorgi: Mainly for people that don't have credit cards. (It was a question asked by another traveller in my hostel in Tbilisi.)

Answer (score 4):

[Yes.](http://www.railway.ge/?web=1&action=page&p_id=197&lang=eng)" ...or in the customers' service offices located in Tbilisi (46/50 M. Kostava Street) and Batumi (5 Mazniashvili Street)"  Those two offices look like the only two they have. [Relevant Google map of the area.](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=46/50%20M.%20Kostava%20Street%20Tbilisi%20Georgia&ll=41.709669,44.785466&spn=0.010877,0.022252&hnear=46-50%20Merab%20Kostava%20St,%20Dzveli%20Tbilisi,%20T%27bilisi,%20Georgia&gl=us&t=m&z=16)

Comment: Aha I already knew about the one in Batumi as I said but nice find for the one in Tbilisi. Too bad it's further away than the train station though (-: